# How to redirect localhost/dir to localhost?

Tags: android, macos, redirect, localhost

I am testing my Android apps and I want to check all layers in my system. I have server on my  macbook and I want to redirect all requests from my Android device to macbook. I installed hosts on Android and change hosts file. Server on mac is working on localhost. Connection with device and pc is Ok. But my app send request like a "localhost/dir/request". 
What I need to do if I don't want change localhost/dir/request in device, and just want to redirect all request like type of localhost/dir/request to  localhost/request on my mac?
How I can redirect all localhost/dir/request to localhost/request?

Comment: You have to convert `localhost/dir/request` to `macip/request` to begin with. `Server on mac is working on localhost`? No useless. That server should work on the LAN address of the mac. What I called macip.

Comment: Yes, right now I compile apk with macip/request URL's in config for testing. But I want to get .apk from production server, install to my test device and test it without changes in code.

Comment: Just add sharedpreferences where the user can choose/edit hosts and dirs. Why all the fuss? What you want starts with a rooted device and if all is possible i don't know. What do you want to test exactly as I don't understand what you mean with `I want to check all layers in my system` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a .htaccess file in your web root folder. Have a look to this [website about the .htaccess file](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/85/Using+.htaccess+rewrite+rules#gs)

Your file would look something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/request$ http://example.com/request [L]
```